# Subfigs of a figure on multiple pages

Tags: latex, figure, multipage

I am facing problem of stacking many figures

The problem is the stack figure is overriding the page dimension vertically and placing all the figure in one page and not changing the page as the limitation of page is reached.

How can page be changed while stacking all the figures.

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{figure}[hp]
\centering
\subfloat[Fig1]{\label{fig:1}\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{fig1}}
\subfloat[Fig2]{\label{fig:2}\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{fig2}}
\subfloat[Fig3]{\label{fig:3}\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{fig3}}
\subfloat[Fig4]{\label{fig:4}\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{fig4}}
\subfloat[Fig5]{\label{fig:5}\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{fig5}}
\subfloat[Fig6]{\label{fig:6}\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{fig6}}
\caption{........}
\label{..........}
\end{figure}
```

I shall be very thankfull for your kind help.

Answer (score 84):

Everything inside `\begin{figure}`...`\end{figure}` must not be larger than a single page. In order to break it over pages, you must do it manually. Use `\ContinuedFloat` from the `subfig` package to do this: (from the [subfig documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig), §2.2.3)

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering 
  \subfloat[][]{...figure code...}% 
  \qquad 
  \subfloat[][]{...figure code...} 
  \caption{Here are the first two figures of a continued figure.}
  \label{fig:cont}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat 
  \centering 
  \subfloat[][]{...figure code...}% 
  \qquad 
  \subfloat[][]{...figure code...} 
  \caption[]{Here are the last two figures of a continued figure.}
  \label{fig:cont}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Does the `subcaption` package have similar function? I've heard `subfig` is depreciated.

Comment: Yes, answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110153/multi-page-figure-with-subcaption-package

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is an old thread, but I recently created the package `figureSeries` which may be a good answer here, you can find it at http://github.com/thomasWeise/figureSeries.

The package `figureSeries` provides

1. a facility to include an arbitrary number of (potentially differently-sized) sub-figures into a figure*-like construct,
2. the ability to make this figure*-like construct look as if it was a floating object, which
3. works well in both single-column and double-column documents.

Answer (score 2):

This may sound odd, but why not put them in something like supertab to make them span several pages? You would get rid of the floating object "figure" which has to placed on one page completely - according to my knowledge.