# pagebreak in latex document

Tags: latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subfigs of a figure on multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078370/subfigs-of-a-figure-on-multiple-pages)

I have inserted some images in a latex document using figure and subfigure, like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfigure[]
{
}
\subfigure[]
{
}
\subfigure[]
{
}

...
\subfigure[]
{
}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that there are about 20 such subfigures which do not fit on a single page. Latex is not inserting any pagebreak here. I also tried inserting page breaks myself after a few figures using newpage commands like `\newpage`, `\clearpage` and even `\pagebreak`, but none of these works.

Could someone please suggest a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to the exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078370/subfigs-of-a-figure-on-multiple-pages. Everything inside a figure environment has to fit on a single page.

Comment: LaTeX related questions are better posted at [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I have flagged this for migration.